# Odoo: Make it impossible to edit a record in tree view?

Tags: xml, treeview, odoo

In Odoo you can make it impossible to create or delete records from the tree view like this:

```
            <tree create="false" delete="false">
                <field name="create_date" readonly="True"/>
            </tree>
```

But I can still click the records and go to the form of that record.
Is there a way to make it impossible to click those records and edit them?

Answer (score 6):

Found it already, need to use `editable="false"`:

```
<tree create="false" delete="false" editable="false">

</tree>
```

Answer (score 5):

Hear it is possible to editable of your tree view to change the attribute of **Tree tag**

just do some things like this

**Editable on Bottom :**

```
<tree create="false" delete="false" editable="bottom">

</tree>
```

**Editable on Top :**

```
<tree create="false" delete="false" editable="top">

</tree>
```

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution for the complete tree view (action) to be read-only is to not provide `form` in the `view_mode` attribute in addition to the `create`, `edit` (and `delete`) options:

```
<record id="hr_timesheet_line_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">hr.analytic.timesheet.tree</field>
    <field name="model">hr.analytic.timesheet</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Timesheet Activities" create="false" edit="false" delete="false">                  
            <field name="date" on_change="on_change_date(date)"/>
            <field name="name"/>
     </tree>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="act_hr_timesheet_line_evry1_all_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Timesheet Activities</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">hr.analytic.timesheet</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
            Click to record activities.
        </p>
    </field>
</record>
```