# How to make a tree editable on top, with "create" button disabled

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I want to get a treview editable inline, I want also to disable the button create.
the problem is: when I hide the button create ( with the arrtibute create=false)
I can't save my edition on the tree.

Comment: please give a code of you are what to do?

Comment: possible duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203548/how-to-make-a-tree-only-editable-inline-no-creation-no-deletion-in-odoo8 (I had exactly same problem)

Comment: @forvas yes, it's the same problem, bbut there is no solution there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Odoo: Make it impossible to edit a record in tree view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611065/odoo-make-it-impossible-to-edit-a-record-in-tree-view)

Answer (score 1):

try as follow. and when put the cursor on "pod_date" field, keying the data and press the "Enter" key. the data will record into the db table.

```
<tree string="Picking list" create="false">
                    <field name="sale_id" readonly="1"/>
                    <field name="pod_date" />
</tree>
```